# Внутренний отступ между элементами в CSS?

Tags: css3, css, html

Допустим, есть два горизонтальных блока **div**:

```
<div></div> Только здесь отступ <div></div>
```

Comment: Желательно без назначения дополнительных классов.

Comment: Опишите задачу более внятно, пожалуйста.

Comment: Есть два блока. Они расположены по горизонтали, примыкая друг к другу. Между ними нужно сделать отступ.

Comment: Что за вопросы? Элементарно же - у первого блока margin-right: 20px или сколько вам нужно. Я же вам, кажется, уже говорил - учитесь пользоваться поиском.

Comment: А если несколько блоков? К тому же я сказал, что желательно не использовать классы.

Comment: У этих блоков должен быть wrapper. Можно присвоить  первому дочернему диву отступ с помощью псевдокласса :first-child. Через JQ тоже можно присвоить маржин

Comment: Спасибо - это решение. Опубликуйте как ответ - я засчитаю.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/674dh708/1/)

```
<section>
  <div>First div</div>
  <div>Second div</div>
</section>

section {
   display:block;
   position:relative;
   width:300px;
   height:50px;
   border:1px solid blue;
}

section div {
    display:inline-block;
    background:red;
    width:100px;
    height:50px; 
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
 }

section div:first-child {
    background:green;
    margin-right:70px;
}
```

Comment: А можно даже и без псевдоклассов ;)

    section div + div {
      background:green;
      margin-left:70px;
    }

Comment: Так и знал, что батька Deonis даст лучший ответ! Преобразуйте в ответ - засчитаю.
____
Проблема лишь в том, что отступы работают лишь для первой линии блоков. Для второй отступ получается слева. Так работает селектор +.